# Unable to fetch table hive_table

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I have created an external hive table in python code using spark, but I have problem when I want to view table using hive shell.

None of these requests works:

```
describe hive_table, SELECT, Alter......

*hive> describe hive_table;
```

> **FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table hive_table. java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: null*

**Creation of external hive table:**

```
(df.write.partitionBy(config['col_part'])
               .mode('overwrite')
               .format(config['format_tbl_hive'])
               .saveAsTable(hive_tbl, path=hive_tbl_dir))
```

Comment: did u see the difference between  table name u saved as and the table name you trying to look for ? why don't you try `describe hive_tbl;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply !!!

when I did : show tables; in hive , I see hive_table as output , but i can't apply queries as SELECT, DESCRIBE, DROP.........

Comment: I like to drop it but I can't !!!!!!

Comment: execute `show tables;`

Comment: It shows me the table,  but i can't drop it !!!!!

Comment: @bms did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem

Comment: you had to delete the metastore of the table in your Mysql database, try to follow the instructions in this link:https://gist.github.com/robcowie/e5772a02d519f2295dbbeb0184503642

Comment: From @jpwhite99 - Converted from an answer to a comment.

I hope you found the answer to your question. If not, here is a post that might solve the issue: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/quot-ERROR-ImpalaRuntimeException-Error-making-dropDatabase/ta-p/294968

Although this is not the exact error you are getting, it is an error that indicates you may have an orphaned entry in your metastore database. The article goes step by step to remove it.