# SemanticException Unable to fetch table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Has anyone got a quick fix for dropping such table please?

- I got a problem when I want to drop a table using hive shell.

```
 hive>> drop table table_1;
```

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table table_1. null (state=42000,code=40000)

and None of these requests works: desc\select\

Comment: sorry to ask, can you pls try `drop table database.table_1;` and also pls check if you have drop access

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The table was corrupted when I tried to drop and recreate it.

I wasn't able to find the actual root cause, but it was fixed by deleting the table's metadata (in MySQL) as mentioned [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/quot-ERROR-ImpalaRuntimeException-Error-making-dropDatabase/ta-p/294968).

Run following commands in MySQL:

```
1. select DB_ID from DBS where NAME='your-database-name'
2. select tbl_id from TBLS where TBL_NAME='your-table-name' and DB_ID=<id from step 1>;
3. delete from PARTITION_KEY_VALS WHERE PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>);
4. delete from PARTITION_PARAMS WHERE PART_ID in (select PART_ID from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>); 
5. delete from PARTITIONS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>; 
6. delete from TBL_COL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>;
7. delete from TBL_PRIVS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>; 
8. delete from TBLS where TBL_ID=<id from step 2>; 
9. COMMIT;
```

other references:

- [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496254/unable-to-fetch-table-hive-table)
- [delete script](https://gist.github.com/robcowie/e5772a02d519f2295dbbeb0184503642)